# Draw a shape in Obj-C (iPad) and see if I tapped it

Tags: ipad, uigesturerecognizer, tap, cgpath

I have two uiviews that are overlapping with some oddly shaped pngs inside. I want to draw an invisible shape over the top of each uiview and detect if I tapped those shapes. Otherwise the tap can be seen by the overlap. I thought my code below would allow this to happen but no touches at all are showing.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    quadrantOnePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(quadrantOnePath, NULL, 30, 214);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(quadrantOnePath, NULL, 281, 47);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(quadrantOnePath, NULL, 493, 51);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(quadrantOnePath, NULL, 306, 376);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(quadrantOnePath);
}

//in viewdidload

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapBlueRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewBlueFloorplans:)];
[tapBlueRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapBlueRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[floorBlueHolderview addGestureRecognizer:tapBlueRecognizer];


// viewbluefunction
-(void)viewBlueFloorplans:(id)sender meso:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

   CGPoint factor = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.view];
   bool processTouch = CGPathContainsPoint(quadrantOnePath, NULL, factor, true);

   if(processTouch) {
    NSLog(@"tap_viewBLU");
   }
}
```

Comment: Is `floorBlueHolderView` the invisible shape?

Answer (score 1):

1, You don't actually have to draw the shape to be able to use CGPathContainsPoint on it. If you know that the shape is correct then put

```
quadrantOnePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(quadrantOnePath, NULL, 30, 214);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(quadrantOnePath, NULL, 281, 47);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(quadrantOnePath, NULL, 493, 51);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(quadrantOnePath, NULL, 306, 376);
CGPathCloseSubpath(quadrantOnePath);
```

into "viewdidload" if the shape does not change. (To prevent memory leaks, don't forget to release quadrantOnePath)
If you wan't to debug the shape, then draw it.

2, `@selector(viewBlueFloorplans:)` will NOT call `-(void)viewBlueFloorplans:(id)sender meso:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer`

`@selector(viewBlueFloorplans:)` WILL call `-(void)viewBlueFloorplans:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer`

3, If you don't actually implement delegate methods, then `[tapBlueRecognizer setDelegate:self];` should not be set (to spare some calculations).